# Sync code between remote computer and desktop while editing

Tags: ubuntu, dropbox, shared

I have an IDE installed on my desktop and would normally test the code on remote computer having ubuntu installed. I feel myself comfortable editing the code in IDE compared to command line editors. So I would like to know if there any good software or some way through which my code is immediately synced to the remote computer so that I can have the command line of my remote computer opened and run the code immediately.

Some thing like a shared file system but get synced ultra fast. I have ubuntu installed in my remote computer and I have admin rights on it. My desktop is mac with 10.8 installed. I have good bandwidth in both my desktop and remote computer but they are located in opposite sides of the globe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a remote Linux machine chances are you have an SSH server running on it for remote access. Which means you can also access your remote filesystem using sftp.

On the Mac you can mount sftp filesystem using OSXFuse (as the sftp device driver) and Macfusion (as the UI to configure sftp connections). Sftp is a sub-protocol of ssh so you login using your normal ssh account.

You can download OSXfuse from here: https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/downloads

And Macfusion from here: http://macfusionapp.org/

When installing OSXFuse, be sure to select "MacFUSE Compatibility Layer" (it's disabled by default).

Once mounted your remote folder will behave just like an external disk so you can open and edit files directly in it. Any changes will automatically be saved over the network.

Comment: If anyone else who upvoted this question want to know how to do this or something similar on Linux and Windows let me know in the comments. I'll edit the answer to include them. For now this answers the OP's requirements.